# performance counters for cache events on Intel Xeon

Tags: intel, cpu-cache, perf

I try to use performance counters (linux `perf`) for Intel Xeon E5 family.

I am rather confused on the interpretation of cache misses. While L1 and LLC values are easily accessible , information for L2 had to be read from registers via the -rNNN event. But on the documentation I haven't found how the event number with the mask field is combined to give the NNN value. Only one example in `perf help` shows a value A8 and a mask of 01 resulting in 1a8. But what is the general rule when masking? Shouldn't it be written in the documentation or it is a standard OR function or something?

Also I haven't understood from the documentation or from other relevant topics' replies, whether LLC values measured in Xeon case are for L3 or L2. What happens when there is third level of cache in the hardware? Does the LLC still measure last level i.e. L3 events?

Has anybody cleared it out?

Comment: Use [the `ocperf.py` wrapper for `perf`](https://github.com/andikleen/pmu-tools) to get symbolic names for uarch-specific events like `mem_load_retired.l2_hit`, `l2_lines_in.all`, `l2_rqsts.all_demand_data_rd` (demand-loads to L2) on Skylake.

Answer (score 1):

May be you can look at the kernel and find out the event numbers for Xeon.

Here is what I found for arm v7 A8

arch/arm/kernel/perf_event_v7.c:168

```
[C(LL)] = {
    [C(OP_READ)] = {
        [C(RESULT_ACCESS)]      = ARMV7_A8_PERFCTR_L2_CACHE_ACCESS,
        [C(RESULT_MISS)]        = ARMV7_A8_PERFCTR_L2_CACHE_REFILL,
    },
```

And arch/arm/kernel/perf_event_v7.c:75

```
ARMV7_A8_PERFCTR_L2_CACHE_ACCESS                = 0x43,
ARMV7_A8_PERFCTR_L2_CACHE_REFILL                = 0x44,
```

So after looking at event number 0x43 and 0x44 in ARM's TRM You can know what exactly they mean

Answer (score 0):

"LLC" stands for Last-Level cache. Most modern Intel systems have 3 levels of cache, so on your processor, the LLC is the L3 cache.